# Do we have structure "somebody/something turns somebody off something"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

I don't know why dictionaries only have this structure

> [turn somebody <-> off](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/turn-off_1?q=turn%20off)
>
> 1. ​to make somebody feel bored or not interested
>
> - *People had been turned off by both candidates in the election.*

The thing is that that structure can not give us freedom to express more complicated idea.

Ok, say Mary's cooking method (she uses a lot of oil and fry a lot) makes me feel I don't want to eat her food.

Do we have structure "**somebody/something turns somebody off something**"?

For example, "**Her cooking style turns me off her food**"

Or do we have to say "**Her cooking style turns my love of her food off**"

**Note:** I still like her in every way. It's just that I don't like her food.

So, if we say "**her cooking style turns me off**", it may make people think that I don't like her as a whole (her character, her clothes her food, etc).

Comment: Saying "Her cooking style turns my love of her food off" doesn't make sense because it sounds like you *do* or *did* love her food.  Also, we say "turns *a person* off *something*", not turns their love of something off.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the construction `something turns somebody off something`.

The verb 'turn off' is a transitive separable multi-word verb, meaning that you can place the direct object between the words and use an indirect object. For this answer, I am referring to the meaning of 'dislike' (and not 'switch off'). For the usage you are asking about, it generally means that a specific example of something has had a wider negative impact that extends beyond that instance. For example:

- Her cooking turned me off Italian food forever.
- Preparing for that exam turned me off language study for years.
- My father ate some spoiled beef once and it turned him off meat.

Comment: Do you think we need "**to**" after "**off**", for example, "**Her cooking turned me off to Italian food forever.**"? I saw this example "**I know that the accident really turned Janet off *to* driving on the highway.**" in the dictionary ( https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/turned+me+off).

Comment: I find the inclusion of _to_ in that sentence strange; I wonder if it's a typo. (It would be more logical to use _from_, but we don't normally include it.)

Comment: @KateBunting, Interesting! So, if we use "**turn somebody off**", we need "**from**", right? However, if we use "**turn somebody on**", we need "**to**" right? For example, "**Her cooking turned me on to Italian food**"?

Comment: Wrong! I said that **we don't normally include ['from']**, though it would be more logical than 'to' in this case.

Comment: We don't need either 'to' or 'from' in this specific construction.

Comment: If I were to include a preposition after "*off*" I would use "of": "*Her cooking turned me off **of** Italian food forever.*" But this is in no way required, nor all that usual.